# Data gets lost when being passed to serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to update the `information` field on my `Profile` model. The endpoint is receiving the data correctly, but it seems like the serializer does not get the data. I don't understand why and none of my attempts to fix it have worked.

**Model:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    information = models.JSONField(null=True)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} Profile'
```

**Endpoint:**

```
class ProfileView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Retrieve the user's profile
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        # Update the information field with the data from the request
        data = request.data
        print(data) # This prints the data correctly
        serializer = self.get_serializer(profile, data=request.data, partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Serializer:**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["user", "information"]
    
    def validate(self, attrs):
        print(attrs) # this prints an empty OrderedDict
        return super().validate(attrs)
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        print(validated_data) # This prints an empty dictionary
        # Update the information field with the data from the request
        instance.information = validated_data["information"]
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

The data i'm passing through the request body:

```
JSON.stringify({"information": {"name": "xxx", "birthday": "xxx}})
```

How is it possible that the data just vanishes? Any help is very appreciated

Comment: Try to use try except on endpoints update funciton, and post what it returns

Comment: It's a key error because it can't find the "information" key in an empty object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm an idiot and forgot to set `"Content-Type": "application/json"` in my request header. Hopefully it will save someone else time.